# Structural geology

Tags: geology, geography

[image]

Map 4 shows two dykes that have been offset by a vertical fault. In different coloured pencils, draw strike lines on each dyke.
(a) On a blank sheet of paper, use the strike lines that you have drawn to construct a fault plane (juxtaposition)
section that illustrates the movement on the fault. Take care to annotate the section fully.
(b) What is the magnitude of the slip vector? Your answer must agree with the section to get the marks.
(c) What is the magnitude and sense (sinistral or dextral) of the strike-slip component of the slip vector? The
magnitude must agree with the section to get the marks.
(d) What is the magnitude and sense (down to the east or down to the west) of the dip-slip component of the slip
vector? Your answer must agree with the section to get the marks.
(e) What is the plunge/plunge direction of the slip vector?

Comment: Homework questions are fine as long as you tell us what you've tried to solve the problem and where you got stuck.